# iOS 8 light status bar not working

Tags: ios, swift

I've set the background color of the main UIView in my view controller to a bluish color.

I've also tried all combinations of the following:

- Adding this to the app delegate:

  `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)`
- Setting View controller status based application to NO and YES
- Setting 'Status Bar Style' to Light in the project overview.

I'm seeing black status bar text when I want to see white text.

I'd like to set the style at the application level, not the VC level.

My info.plist:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Status bar style is determined (by default) at the level of the view controller, not the application. Implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` in your view controller.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .LightContent
    }
}
```

You *can* determine status bar style at the application level, but to do so, you must throw a switch in your *Info.plist*. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarStyle:animated:):

> To opt out of the view controller-based status bar appearance behavior, you must add the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key with a value of NO to your app’s *Info.plist* file, *but doing so is not recommended* [my italics, and I don't even know whether this is even supported any longer].

Comment: Is that a function I override?

Comment: Ideally it would be the same for all VCs and I'd only have to set in one place

Comment: Then you need to throw the Info.plist switch that allows you to set it at the application level.

Comment: @maxhud what is the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarStyle:animated:

Comment: Well, I can't see your Info.plist, so how do I know more? Your question doesn't _ask_ your question.

Comment: I'll post my .plist but I did set that key with the value no.

Comment: Also please state clearly what result you expect and what result you see. It is not clear to me that you know what `.LightContent` _means_. Maybe you are getting `.LightContent` but you don't know it when you see it.

Comment: I updated my question. Your individual VC code does make the text white, but I'd like an application level solution.

Comment: As a sidenote, this won't work on view controllers that are embedded inside a `UINavigationController` or another class of container, because that container will override all it's child view controllers. Give your `UINavigationController` a custom class and, inside of that class, define a method that takes the `preferredStatusBarStyle` from the first view controller, like this: `override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle { return self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first.preferredStatusBarStyle() }`

Answer (score 15):

**for all IOS 9+**

In your plist file change add/change your table  with these 2 lines.

1) `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`

2) `Status bar style` to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`

[image]

If you want to **change style in running app** for any reason use this

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

this saved my life numerous times! :-)

Comment: Where is the screenshot from? I hope the screenshot was a bit bigger showed where this was taken from.

Comment: from your info.plist file in root of your project in xcode

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

In **Info.plist** add this property

**View controller-based status bar appearance to NO**

and after that in **AppDelegate** inside the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** add these code

**UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false**

**UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent**

Comment: I don't think this is Swift 4 but it does still work for now.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

might be Solve this issue.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.